# Deleting a node in circular linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, circular-list

I have a basic linked list problem that I have attempted to solve below. I would appreciate any inputs on my approach, correctness of the algorithm (and even coding style). The problem calls for a function that deletes all occurrences of an int in a circular linked list and returns any node from the list or NULL (when the list is null).

Here's some C++ code that I have so far:

```
struct Node{
    Node* next;
    int data;
};

Node* deleteNode(Node* &node, int num){

    if(!node){
        return NULL;
    }

    Node* given = node;
    Node* del;

    while(node->next != given){
        if(node->next->data == num){
            del = node->next;
            node->next = node->next->next;
            delete del;
        }
        node = node->next;
    }

    //Check if the first node needs to be deleted, with variable node pointing to last element
    if(given->data == num){
        node->next = given->next;
        delete given;
    }

    return node;
}
```

Comment: You asked for style comments so here is one. You should create a List class, and deleteNode should be a private member of that class. You should think in terms of the interface that your code presents to the user of your code. No user of a List class needs or wants to know about Nodes, they just want to add and remove items from their list. Have a look at std::list for an example of good design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `delete node;` should be `delete del;`.

Also, use `Node* node` as parameter, instead of `Node* &node` which will prevent non-lvalues from passing in.

p.s. Forgot a semicolon after struct definition? :)

Comment: Do you need to put a ; after a struct? I thought that was only for classes

Comment: @yzn-pku Thanks! The first issue is a typo :)  Regarding 2nd point, correct me if I'm wrong but I think if I use "Node* node" then I won't be changing the actual node pointer. That's why I used a reference to Node pointer. And yes, will add the semicolon after struct :)

Comment: @Jesse, in C++ a struct and a class are almost the same thing, the only difference is the default access modifier: it's `public` for structs and `private` for classes

Comment: @KT100 Do you have to also return the node through the parameter? If not you don't need the &.

Answer (score 1):

Without following all your logic I can see at a glance this code cannot work.

You are checking for the input list being empty and that's the only case in which your code returns `NULL`. But what happens if you are passed a list in which all elements must be deleted?

This problem also has a subtlety in it. To check if you completed a circular list you need to compare to the first address to see if you got linked back to the start. However if this element has been deleted then by C++ standard you're **not even allowed to use its address in a comparison**.

To avoid making two passes over the elements to be deleted one possible trick is to "break the loop" when starting iteration so you can check for `NULL` instead of checking for the address of the starting node.

Comment: The corner case when all elements need to be deleted is a great catch. This code will definitely fail then. How would you recommend modifying the while loop to take care of that? I am thinking along the lines of ensuring the pointers being deleted to be set to NULL, so that we ensure that in the end, the variable node being returned equals NULL for that case. Please note that I check for the first element of the list only in the end, so your 2nd comment would not be valid AFAIK. Also, could you please further elaborate (with code example) on breaking the loop? Thanks!

Comment: I took now the time to actually read your code and I can see another problem in your approach. If in the end you find that the `given` node must be deleted you also need to fix the pointer that is linking to it. For example given the list `(2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 7)` if you are given the first `2` and are told to delete all `2` you will end up with `(2, 3, 4, 5, 7)` after the loop and then you check about deleting `given`, but you also need to fix the `next` pointer of node `7`.